# Unable to installl Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHub.Android nuget to existing project

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, nuget, azure-notificationhub

I got the following error when I was trying to install Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHub.Android nuget package to my existing xamarin.forms project.

> One or more unresolved package dependency constraints detected in the existing packages.config file. All dependency constraints must be resolved to add or update packages. If these packages are being updated this message may be ignored, if not the following error(s) may be blocking the current package operation: 'Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.617 constraint: Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData (>= 2.1.0)', 'Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.617 constraint: Xamarin.Google.Android.Material (>= 1.0.0)', 'Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.617 constraint: Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4 (>= 1.0.0)', 'Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.617 constraint: Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser (>= 1.0.0)'

> Unable to find a version of 'Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common' that is compatible with 'Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Runtime 1.1.1.3 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common (= 1.1.1.3)', 'Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData 1.1.1.3 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common (= 1.1.1.3)', 'Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core 1.1.1.3 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common (= 1.1.1.3)'.

But my project already has Xamarin.Android.Arch.*** 1.1.1.3 installed.

I had no issue when installing Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHub.Android nuget to a fresh project. The error occurs when installing to one my existing Xamarin.Forms project which already uses AppCenter.
Is this because of some package dependency conflict? If so, how to resolve it?

Comment: Have you installed the above package?

Comment: What did you mean by above package? Xamarin.Android.Arch.*?

Comment: I mean Xamarin.AndroidX.xxxx packages and what's your Xamarin.forms version,did you try to update them ?

Comment: When I tried to install one of Xamarin.AndroidX.xxxx packages, I am getting a same kind of error:
Unable to find a version of 'Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState' that is compatible with 'Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity 1.1.0.4 constraint: Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState (>= 1.1.0.3-alpha01)', 'Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment 1.2.5.3 constraint: Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState (>= 1.1.0.3-alpha01)', 'Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModelSavedState 2.2.0.3 constraint: Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState (>= 1.1.0.3-alpha01)'.

Comment: My xamarin.android project uses a package.config file to keep the installed packages. Is this could be the problem?

Comment: Try to add `developmentDependency="true"`  to your package.config to avoid including dependency.Like  `<package id="xxx" version="xx" developmentDependency="true" />`

Comment: The issue was related to a package conflict. When package.config was migrated to PackageReference, Package Manager clearly showed where the conflict is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHub.Android (1.1.1)` package uses `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base (>= 70.x.x)` and `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging (>= 70.x.x)` as dependencies. One of the packages installed on the project also depends on `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base` package. `Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHub.Android (1.1.1)` package needs a higher version of `GooglePlayservices.Base (>= 70.x.x)`package. Since my project uses a package.config file to manage installed packages, the existing package already installed a lower version of GooglePlayservices.Base package (60.x.x).

I was able to resolve this issue in 2 ways:

1. Uninstall the package which creates the conflict with all its dependencies. Then reinstall the package with setting Dependency Behavior as Lowest. Then I was able to install NotificationHub.Android package without any errors.
2. [Migrate from package.config to new PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) format. In this way, it's easier to see what are the packages directly installed on the project and don't have to worry about dependencies. This also shows which packages create the conflict. Fixed the issue as the error log suggested.

> NU1107: Version conflict detected for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement. Install/reference Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 71.1620.4 directly to project XXX to resolve this issue.
> XXX -> Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.Android 1.1.1 -> Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 71.1740.4 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (>= 71.1620.4)